# Should DAO methods receive a data object as parameter or just its contents?

Tags: design-patterns, dao

I am thinking about two different approaches for a DAO and I was wondering which is more correct. Let's say that we have the following class:

```
public class Employee {

private int id;
private String name;

//getters and setters

}
```

And the following two approaches for the DAO:

A)

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public Employee insert(int id, String name) {
    ...
    }
```

B) :

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public Employee insert(Employee employee) {
    ...
    }
```

My question is whether both approaches are correct and/or one of them is more correct than the other.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is better

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public Employee insert(Employee employee) {
       //Operations
    }
```

Because if you want add new propriety for operation with DAO this method keeps the implementation of the dao unchanged, instead the first method forces you to do something like this, which becomes constricted if the dao are many

```
public class EmployeeDao {

    public Employee insert(int id, String name, Object otherObject) {
       //Operations
    }
```

Comment: on the other hand, if we change the Employee class then we should also perform the corresponding changes in the Employee table and consequently in the DAO.  E.g. if I add the 'address' field to Employee, then we should also add the 'address' column to the table and change the insert implementation for this matter.

Comment: Yes but if you have DAODatabaseJson, DAODatabaseXml, DAODatabaseHibernate, and only in the DAODatabaseJson you want to add the information for json deserialization json, if you use the second method you can leave the other DAO unaltered , but if you have the different DAO with the same interface and add new argument to the function you must change all DAO method